# How to display saved information from SharedPreferences?

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

I want to display the username on the user profile that the user inputs on the first activity. I am using SharedPreferences, but the following code does not display the username on the other activity.

This is the code on the activity where the user inputs the username:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText userName, password;
    Button b1;

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userName=findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
        password=findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
        b1=findViewById(R.id.button);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        binding.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(binding.usernameText.length()==0 && binding.passwordText.length()==0){
                    binding.fillInTheBlanks.setText("Please, fill in the blanks.");
                    binding.passwordConstraint.setText("");
                }
                else{
                    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("database", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                    editor.putString("Username", userName.getText().toString());
                    editor.apply();

                    binding.fillInTheBlanks.setText("");
                    binding.passwordConstraint.setText("");
                    startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), YourGenderActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the code where I want to read and display saved information from SharedPreferences:

```
public class MyProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_profile_activity);

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String userstring =  sp.getString("Username",null);

        TextView username = findViewById(R.id.userName);
        username.setText(userstring); //this does not do anything on the activity
    }

    public void homeActivity(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

If there is another way to achieve this, any help is welcome.

Comment: seems you are using two different sharePreferences. to set you used "database" and to retrieve you used "getDefaultSharedPreferences". use same at both places.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want an implementation of `SharedPreferences`, you can do it like that:

To write to the `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("database", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                    editor.putString("Username", username);
                    editor.apply();
```

To retrieve information:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            String userstring =  sp.getString("Username",null);
```

Another problem is the implementation of context is `new Intent(v.getContext())` it could be as simple as
`startActivity(this, YourGenderActivity.class));`

This code snippet just uses `this` for the context then it is similar with next profile context `this`

NOTES:

1. Both writing and reading operations have to have the **same Context**.
2. SharedPreferences should write to inside **a singleton** to make it easy to set and get value

Comment: Do you get any error message, or could you post more information so that we can help you more efficiently?

Comment: No, I do not get an error message, the information from SharedPreferences is not displayed on the activity (I want it to be displayed on the activity that represents the user's profile). I do not know if it is saved in SharedPreferences at all.

Comment: The Problem is that you are not refrencing the same context. You write the prefrence with one context and retrieve it with another class. That is the key error. Try to use getApplicationContext(); as context.

Comment: Ok, could you post a more detailed answer? Probably the Code of the classes you are tring to work with??

Comment: I updated my question with the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 2 different `SharedPreferences` objects. You need to get the same one using `getSharedPreferences("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` in both activities. By using `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`, you're using a `SharedPreferences` object that is associated to your package name (nothing wrong with using that, but I prefer to be explicit).

Answer (score 0):

You have specified a name for your shared preference named 'database'

In your second activity you must exactly get that name again so

use this in your second activity:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("database", MODE_PRIVATE);
String userstring =  sp.getString("Username",null);
```

In SharedPreference you can have multiple names to arrange your data for example you can specify a name for all data related to theme,database and...

to get android default name for sharedPreference use :

```
SharedPreferences sp = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```